# Is "Cantor expansion" applied in any computer technologies?

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation

The [Cantor expansion](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2004/vol5-n1/paper4/v5n1-4pd.pdf) of the natural number n is

```
 n = ak * k!+a(k − 1) *(k −1)!+.... + a2 * 2!+a1 *1!
```

where all the ai (digits) satisfy 0 ≤ ai ≤ i

I knew it can be used to generate full-permutation, even some questions about it comes up in interviews, but I hasn't yet seen where it's applied in computer technologies. Anyone has any clue on this?

Comment: This is never used in practice. Those interviewers must be psychos. Or there is something you don't tell us.

Comment: What I don't tell you is that my friend who is a CS student learnt this algorithm in order to generate full-permutation and he asked me this question ...  Anyway I believe it can be used somewhere.

Comment: In Wikipedia it is called the factorial number system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system . It does seem to have some interesting connections with the Johnson-Trotter method for iterating through permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Searching with keyword "cantor expansion" in Google Patent, I found an [example](https://www.google.com.hk/patents/CN103118139A?cl=en&dq=cantor+expansion&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwB2oVChMI_M-I0endyAIVRKeUCh0atwbn) which used cantor expansion to encode info.

> ...... the recipient will extract an arrangement which g a head keywords: H
>   '1; H' 2, ..., H 'g. Next, we can further expansion by Cantor:
>
> [0034] k = a [l] * (g_l)! + A [2] * (g_2)! + ... + A [g] * 0! + L
>
> [0035] The calculation of the arrangement is that the partial ordering
>   of the k-th order, then the HTTP request is encoded n_segk fragments.
>   Wherein, a [u] represents the arrangement satisfies H '' 
>   number H' j of u's. Then the packet format HTTP Ci requests sent to
>   fixedly hold the partial order of the i-th order, so as to achieve the
>   purpose of transferring data distributed fragmentation. Such
>   analytical methods can hide and maintain maximum independence and
>   encoding and retrieval accuracy. Wherein, l <= i, j, u, k <= 2n.